# How to make a frustum of a cone

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, finite-element-method

For finite element purposes I need a frustum of a cone with a finite wall thickness, i.e. a tapered pipe.

To make a cone is easy

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
c = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}, 0.12]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[c]; mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So my idea was to use RegionDifference to make a frustum. Here is my module.

```
ClearAll[coneFrustum];
coneFrustum::usage = 
  "coneFrustum[{pt1, pt2, },r1 ,r2 ,height] generates a frustum of \
cone with axis going from pt1 to pt2 and with radii r1, r2";
coneFrustum[{{x1_, y1_, z1_}, {x2_, y2_, z2_}}, r1_, r2_, L_] := 
 Module[{cL, vec},
  cL = L r1/(r1 - r2);
  vec = ({x2, y2, z2} - {x1, y1, z1})/
   Norm[{x2, y2, z2} - {x1, y1, z1}];
  RegionDifference[
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    Cone[{{x1, y1, z1}, cL vec}, r1]
    ],
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    Cone[{{x2, y2, z2}, (cL - L) vec}, r2]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

This is what I get for a solid frustum

```
cf1 = coneFrustum[{{-0.1, 0, 0}, {-0.3, 0, 0}}, 0.12, 0.1, 0.2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So I have my frustum but I have not managed to take away the part of the cone beyond the frustum. I have a hollow shell of the difference of the cones.

Is there a better way of doing this?  I still have to go on to subtract a smaller inner frustum to make my hollow shape.

**Edit**

As kglr pointed out I made a simple error with my code. The tip has to have the same coordinates. Here is the corrected version.

```
ClearAll[coneFrustum];
coneFrustum::usage = 
  "coneFrustum[{pt1, pt2}, r1,r2, height] generates a frustum of cone \
with axis going from pt1 to pt2 and with radii r1, r2";
coneFrustum[{{x1_, y1_, z1_}, {x2_, y2_, z2_}}, r1_, r2_, L_] := 
 Module[{cL, vec},
  cL = L r1/(r1 - r2);
  vec = ({x2, y2, z2} - {x1, y1, z1})/
   Norm[{x2, y2, z2} - {x1, y1, z1}];
  RegionDifference[
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    Cone[{{x1, y1, z1}, cL vec}, r1]
    ],
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    Cone[{{x2, y2, z2}, cL vec}, r2]
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

Now we make two frustums and subtract.

```
cf1 = coneFrustum[{{-0.1, 0, 0}, {-0.3, 0, 0}}, 0.12, 0.1, 0.2];
cf2 = coneFrustum[{{-0.1, 0, 0}, {-0.3, 0, 0}}, 0.1, 0.08, 0.2];
reg = RegionDifference[cf1, cf2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And to get the mesh

```
mesh = ToElementMesh[reg]; mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The method from Henrik Schumacher below using `ImplicitRegion` is also a good solution.

Are there any good reasons why one could be better than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}, 0.12]];
k = .2;
d = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cone[{{-k, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}, (1 - k) 0.12]];
RegionDifference[c, d]
```

[image]

Comment: And `RegionDifference[RegionDifference[c, d], RegionDifference[a, b]]` with `a = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}, 0.1]];
b = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
   Cone[{{-k, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}, (1 - k) 0.1]];` cuts out the interior nicely. Well done (+1).

Comment: Why does yours work and not mine? I think it is the same idea...

Comment: @Hugh, the two cones should  have the same tip, so if you change `(cL - L) vec` to  `cL vec` your code gives the same result.

Comment: Thank you @Henrik.

Comment: Rats! Simple error. Back to school for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You mean something like this?

```
n = 36;
rout1 = 1.;
rout2 = 0.8;
rin1 = .9;
rin2 = 0.7;
h1 = 1.;
h2 = 0.;
R = MeshRegion[
 Join[
  Join[CirclePoints[rout1, n], ConstantArray[h1, {n, 1}], 2], 
  Join[CirclePoints[rout2, n], ConstantArray[h2, {n, 1}], 2], 
  Join[CirclePoints[rin1, n], ConstantArray[h1, {n, 1}], 2], 
  Join[CirclePoints[rin2, n], ConstantArray[h2, {n, 1}], 2]
  ],
 With[{
   edges = Partition[#, 2, 1, 1] & /@ Partition[Range[4 n], n]
   },
  Polygon@Join[
    Join[edges[[1]], Reverse /@ edges[[2]], 2],
    Join[edges[[3]], Reverse /@ edges[[4]], 2],
    Join[edges[[1]], Reverse /@ edges[[3]], 2],
    Join[edges[[2]], Reverse /@ edges[[4]], 2]
    ]
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[R]; mesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

This is quick and robust but it is not so easy to create adaptive meshes with this method.

**Edit:**

Here is another way utilizing `ImplicitRegion`.

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[{0.5 <= z <= 1, 0.1 z^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 0.12 z^2}, {{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, 0.5, 1}}],
 MaxCellMeasure -> (1 -> 0.02)
 ]
```

`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` has a bit of trouble to detect all parts of the mantle for larger values of `MaxCellMeasure`, so this is not super robust. But is allows the use of `MeshRefinementFunction` in order to create adaptive meshes.

[image]

Comment: Gosh, that was so fast I would guess you had done this before. Thanks. You seem to be recommending building from polygons.  What happens if I want a fine mesh at one location that is part of a curved surface rather than  built-up from polygons? I think with your method I have to put in lots of polygons rather than use a mesh refinement function.

Comment: You're welcome. And yeah, you're right. A true adaptive discretization is not possible this way. =/ At least not that easily.

Answer (score 1):

In recent version you can directly use Boolean operations to get quite good results:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
outer = Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}, 0.12];
inner = Cone[{{0, 0, 0}, {-0.8, 0, 0}}, 0.10];
box = Cuboid[{-1/4, -1, -1}, {0, 1, 1}];
reg = RegionDifference[outer, inner]; reg = 
 RegionIntersection[reg, box];
MeshRegion[ToBoundaryMesh[reg]]
```

[image]